# Why $P(A+B)$ is equal to$ P(A)+P(B)−P(B|A)P(A)$ if $A$ and $B$ are dependent events?

Tags: probability

I understand why $P(A+B)=P(A)+P(B)−P(AB)$ for independent events. After all, if $A$ and $B$ share same outcomes (like event $A$ is that a die will show an even number, while $B$ is the same die showing a prime number. $2$ is a prime number, so they share outcome) then by just adding their probabilities we double count their shared outcomes (We need to remember that $A+B$ means probability that at the least one outcome of either $A$ or $B$ will take place. So shared outcomes cause double counting). We compensate it by using "$-P(AB)$", i.e. we take away probability that a shared outcome will happen.

Alas, but the same logic doesn't seem to work for dependent events, there is no need for shared outcomes for two events to be dependent. I just don't understand why we need "$−P(B|A)P(A)$" instead of "$-P(AB)$".

Even a hint would be appreciated.

Comment: $P(A\cap B)=P(B\mid A)P(A)$.

Comment: It's true for all events.

Comment: Oops. Seems like I totally missed fact that P(AB)=P(B|A)P(A), silly me. So the formula is universal for all events, no matter is independent or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes a figure is worth a thousand words:

[image]